# Narcissist routine in Swift

Tags: swift, linux

I am trying to translate the Narcissist routine from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Narcissist#Python) into Swift script in Linux.

The aim is to take the contents of the script itself and check against information given by the user. If identical, return True or Accept. In python it looks like:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[0]) as quine:
    code = raw_input("Enter source code: ")
    if code == quine.read():
        print("Accept")
    else:
        print("Reject")
```

I haven't made too far as:

```
#! /usr/bin/swift

let script = CommandLine.arguments[0]
let mytext = String.init(contentsOfFile: script)
```

leads to error:

```
./command.swift:4:21: error: argument labels '(contentsOfFile:)' do not match any available overloads
let mytext = String.init(contentsOfFile: script)
                    ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

- How do I load the contents of the (running) script into a variable using Swift?
- What is an overload in Swift lingo?

Comment: So what's your actual issue?

Comment: Note that `String.init(contentsOf:)` expects a `URL` argument, whereas you're probably looking for `String.init(contentsOfFile:)` which expects a `String` arguement

Comment: The issue is, as stated, to load the script contents into a variable. The same script is being executed. Further,  how can I expand .arguments[0] to a complete URL?

Comment: That's not an issue, that's a goal, or problem statement. An issue would be something that you run into on your way towards achieving that goal. You haven't mentioned any such attempts, or what issues have stopped you from achieving this goal.

Comment: And as I said, you don't need a `URL`, because you can just use `String.init(contentsOfFile:)` instead of `String.init(contentsOf:)`. If you really did need a `URL`, for some other reason, you can use [`URL.init(fileURLWithPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780183-init)

Comment: Updated the question, this lead me to an error. It points to not matching an existing overload. Is String.init the proper function to load contents from the system? Can you point to documentation?

Comment: @if_araujo Strange Swift quirk: lots of string processing capabilities, and other behaviour don't become available unless you `import Foundation`. As for what overloading is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful comments, I found the solution for the problem. Below is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/swift
import Foundation

let script = CommandLine.arguments[0]
print(script)
let mytext = try? String.init(contentsOfFile: script, encoding: .utf8)

var enteredtext = readLine()
if mytext == enteredtext {
    print("Accept")
} else {
    print("Reject")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first create variable empty

```
var text = ""
```

then in

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


   let script = CommandLine.arguments[0]
   text = String(contentsOf: script)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why override? `error: 'override' can only be specified on class members`

Comment: You seem to have repeated (func viewDidLoad()) It is used only once in the class

Comment: @MajedDkahellalah, `viewDidLoad()` is used in iOS apps (or recent macOS apps). The OP is asking about Swift on Linux as a scripting language.